# How to draw \hrule based on text width?

Tags: width, calculations, lengths, textwidth, calc

I have a `\divider` command where it draws a thick hrule and a thin hrule to achieve the style I want:

```tex
\newcommand{\divider}[1]{%
    \vskip-2pt %
    {%
        \color{black}%
        \hrule%
    }%
    \nointerlineskip%
    \noindent%
    {%
        \color{black}%
        \hrule width #1 height 1pt%
    }%
    \vskip5pt%
}
```

**Result:**
[image: example]

Since I'm using a non-fixed width font, I want it to take one  argument to let it know how long will the thick line be. For example, `\divider{SKILLS}` will draw a thick hrule based on the width of "SKILLS" with my current font.

How can I do this? Is it the correct usage of `\widthof`?

*Try#1*

I tried to use `\widthof` from the `calc` package like this:

```tex
\divider{\widthof{SKILLS}}
```

But this didn't work even if I added "pt" after `#1`

Comment: I haven't used Calc yet, but you probably must put the "Skills" into a mbox. Currently it is a series of boxes. In general, you can use savebox. Save the content into a box, measure the size, insert the box and insert the line, then hrulefill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{calc}
\newcommand{\divider}[1]{%
    \vskip-2pt %
    {%
        \color{black}%
        \hrule%
    }%
    \nointerlineskip%
    \noindent%
    {%
        \color{black}%
        \hrule width #1 height 1pt%
    }%
    \vskip5pt%
}

\newlength{\mywidth}
\newcommand{\myheading}[1]{\noindent #1%
                           \smallskip%
                           \setlength{\mywidth}{\widthof{#1}}%
                           \divider{\mywidth}}

\begin{document}

\myheading{SKILLS}

\myheading{LENGTHY TEXT THAT NEEDS A WIDER LINE}

\end{document}
```